# Customise Rails validation errors conditionally

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain, validationerror

I am using `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc` to customise validation
errors in my Rails app. I created an initializer as follows:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html = %(<div class="control-group error">#{html_tag}</div>)
  elements = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_tag).css "label, input"
  elements.each do |e|
    if e.node_name.eql? 'label'
      e['class'] = "control-label"
      html = %(#{e})
    elsif e.node_name.eql? 'input'
      html = %(<div class="controls">)
      if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
        html += %(#{html_tag}<span class="help-inline">&nbsp;#{instance.error_message.first}</span>)
      else
        html += %(#{html_tag}<span class="help-inline">&nbsp;#{instance.error_message}</span>)
      end
      html += %(</div>)
    end
  end
  html.html_safe
end
```

I want to customize the markup only if the subdomain is `fisheye` though,
otherwise, I want to use different markup. How do I achieve that? I though
it would be possible since `instance` is passed to the block.

Comment: You only want to get the subdomain and make a condition with it ?

Comment: basically yes, but I'm in an initializer.